# Googleドライブに保存されているExcelファイルをダウンロードしたい

Tags: google-apps-script

現在、GASを使用してGoogleドライブに保存されているExcelファイルをダウンロードしたいと考えております。
なお、そのExcelファイルについては、スプレッドシートからExcelファイルに変換させています。
下記のサイトを参考に作成しておりますが、想定通りに動かない状態です。
そもそも、GASを使用してマイドライブにあるExcelファイルをダウンロードすることは可能なのでしょうか。
セキュリティ上、難しいという記事も拝見しました。
もし、Excelファイルをダウンロードすることが可能でしたら、ご教示いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[ローカルにテキストファイルをダウンロードする方法を説明しているサイトになります。](https://googleappsscript.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/09/06/120000)

Comment: 「Google ドライブから直接ダウンロード」が一番手っ取り早そうですが、あえてこの手順を踏もうとしている理由はなぜでしょうか？ / 例えば、スプレッドシートから Excel ファイルを出力していったん Google ドライブに保存、そのファイルをダウンロードさせたい…とかでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick さん　
ご連絡ありがとうございます。 
＞例えば、スプレッドシートから Excel ファイルを出力していったん Google ドライブに保存、 そのファイルをダウンロードさせたい…とかでしょうか？ 
 →上記、ご認識通りです。ご教示の程、お願いします。